# unresponsive product image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having this issue that I have been trying to debug for the last 24 hr. I made this shopping cart with HTML and CSS and JS. I first made the side list witch mounted correctly; its only CSS and html, but then when I made the item menu by running a **function** with a **return statement**, and **template-literals** to embed the image with its border, it does not show up on the browser. I already debugged all my code from all the obvious mistakes that I made and the console is not reporting any errors,  but for some reason I still cant load the image on my menu. I just don't know where my problem is!

Here lies my progress, as you can see its a pretty large "rabbit hole" it starts with the heading and then the item menu and finally the product menu. I have made the connection with the CSS which is "stats.css" and added the JavaScript within the html with `<script></script>` tags.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 4em;
  width: 70%;
  background: #3a3b3c;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2em;
}

.header .logo {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cart {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
}

.cart p {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#root {
  width: 60%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #808080;
  margin-left: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.head {
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.foot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #212329;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #212329;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.img-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.images {
  max-width: ;
  max-height: ;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 110px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #212329;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>
   perfume
  </title>
  <link href="stats.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <p class="logo">
    Amazon, Spend less smile more
   </p>
   <div class="cart">
    <i class="bi bi-cart4">
    </i>
    <p id="count">
     0
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
   <div id="root">
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="head">
     <p>
      My Stuff
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="cartItem">
     Your cart is Empthy
    </div>
    <div class="foot">
     <h3>
      Total
     </h3>
     <h2 id="total">
      $ 0.00
     </h2>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const product = [
      {
        id: 0,
        image: "product/perfume.jpeg",
        title: "Victoria Secret Perfume",
        price: 50,
      },
    ];

    const categories = [
      ...new Set(
        product.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
      ),
    ];
    let i = 0;

    ///HERE is the return statement!
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTMl = categories
      .map((item) => {
        let { image, title, price } = item;
        return (
          `<div class= 'box'>
                        <div class= 'img-box'>
                                <img class='images' src=${image}></img>

                                </div>
                            <div class='bottom'>
                            <p>${title}</p>

                            <h2>$ ${price}.00  </h2>` +
          "<button onclick='addtocart(" +
          i++ +
          ")'>Add to cart</button>" +
          `</div>
                            </div>`
        );
      })
      .join("");

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *it does not show up on the browser* `.innerHTMl` -> `.innerHTML`  This at least adds the img-box.  Formatted code in-case there's some other issue and save someone the effort:  https://jsfiddle.net/o9ueyhwL/

Comment: Please don't make your question title a greeting. Question titles are used to as a search tool for users who are trying to find previously asked questions that may relate to their issue so the title should be short and concise.

Comment: Adding to @freedomn-m's comment, that typo should have been shown as an error in your developer console; have you checked that?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

Comment: @mykaf I also thought that at first, but because it's *setting* a property, there's no error and just adds a new property (that does nothing): https://jsfiddle.net/njb1tcka/1/

Comment: Yes I duble-checked the "console.log" and there is no issue, I also checked the folder that contains the image and I wrote the name of the image correctly as well.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for uploading my code on fiddle.net it looks excellent, the only thing  missing is my image folder. It looks like it worked really well over there.

Answer (score 0):

### Main Issues:

- **Typos** use `innerHTML` instead of innerHTMl
- **Container's width** `.img-box` had width of **100%** which means it is allowed to use full screen
  width while its the container for the image it won't be able  to sever
  the desired function.
  fix I changed `.img-box` width to auto at the same time given
  same height to `img` tag via `height` attribute.

So the revised HTML and CSS files are here:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 4em;
  width: 70%;
  background: #3a3b3c;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2em;
}

.header .logo {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cart {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
}

.cart p {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#root {
  width: 60%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #808080;
  margin-left: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.head {
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.foot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #212329;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #212329;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.img-box {
  width: auto;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.images {
  /* max-width: ;
    max-height: ; */
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 110px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #212329;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link href="./stats.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>
    perfume
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p class="logo">
      Amazon, Spend less smile more
    </p>
    <div class="cart">
      <i class="bi bi-cart4">
    </i>
      <p id="count">
        0
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="head">
        <p>
          My Stuff
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="cartItem">
        Your cart is Empthy
      </div>
      <div class="foot">
        <h3>
          Total
        </h3>
        <h2 id="total">
          $ 0.00
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const product = [{
      id: 0,
      image: "https://i5.walmartimages.com/seo/Victoria-s-Secret-Love-Spell-Mist-Perfume-for-Women_6a272ee9-b7d6-45fe-8d91-793a2a6b0fae.5559139f02513828623a858f49fcab95.jpeg",
      title: "Victoria Secret Perfume",
      price: 50,
    }, ];

    const categories = [
      ...new Set(
        product.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
      ),
    ];
    let i = 0;

    ///HERE is the return statement!
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = categories
      .map((item) => {
        let {
          image,
          title,
          price
        } = item;
        return (
          `<div class= 'box'>
                        <div class= 'img-box'>
                                <img class='images' height="180" src=${image} />

                                </div>
                            <div class='bottom'>
                            <p>${title}</p>

                            <h2>$ ${price}.00  </h2>` +
          "<button onclick='addtocart(" +
          i++ +
          ")'>Add to cart</button>" +
          `</div>
                            </div>`
        );
      })
      .join("");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```